# Consequences of the lack of acknowledgment on last message

Tags: tcp

until not long ago, I had not deeply thought about a single limitation that even TCP has, which is visible in the well-known [two-generals problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Generals%27_Problem)

Since I've stumbled across this problem, I started wondering which are the consequences that may arise from the impossibility of solving the problem. Lets consider the email protocol. When A sends a mail to B, A receives a acknowledge confirming that B indeed receive its message. Still, B ends up not knowing if A receive the acknowledge. Why isn't this important? I'm trying to understand why the impossibility of consensus is not a big deal in everyday applications and we do know worry about this (maybe I'm overthinking things).

Another situations I've thought about pertains to ATM machines. Lets say that someone wants to withdraw 50$, the transaction is accepted at the bank headquarters, so the Money is subtracted from the balance, but consider that the connection between the headquarters and the ATM fails at this point. The Money is discounted but the machine does not deliver the Money. How are these situations handled?

Maybe I'm  a bit too confused, but this is all new to me. It seems weird that even during a conversation between people, the person who says the last sentence has no way to know if the other person heard the sentence, since the last sentence has to be left without an acknowledgement.

Answer (score 1):

This is handled on an application-to-application basis, depending on the business logic:

- SMTP: Worst thing to happen is, the mail is sent twice. Today's mail servers will see the duplicate id and drop the second copy
- ATM: The money is only reserved in the first step, only after the user took out the money is it converted from a reservation to a withdrawal. This is in fact a lot more complicated, as all steps are logged locally on the device ("Counting money ... OK", "Opening slot ... OK", "Shoving money out of slot ... OK", ...) to be able to roll back or forward in the event the machine, the connection or the power fails at a bad moment.